# Yandex Map Kit Android

Tags: android, android-studio, yandex, yandex-maps

I am going to use yandex maps in my Android project. I did how it is illustrated in the documentation,but I am getting this error during compiling

[image]

Comment: When asking questions here, please include the error message as text. Then the text of the error message gets indexed by search engines. Also, having the error message as text makes it accessible for people who use screen readers. Please [edit] your question to include the text of the error message, as text.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than 64k classes in your application.
You should use [multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex).

Comment: I added implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' dependecy, but I am still getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: You should also add multidex enabled in buildconfig!

Comment: And extend your application class from MultidexApplication

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I put in where you said. But Unfortunately, It is showing the problem again. I saw in Yandex FAQ, They say to put android.enableD8=false, Then It is working fine, but this is warning as depricated and will be removed in the future